# Show convergence of sequence with infinite series as inequality

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I've got a question concerning some weird kind of Lipschitz constant function, but it's an introduction course in Mathematics so Lipschitz hasn't passed the course yet. I should be able to prove this just by convergence of series, sequences and showing Cauchy. Here's the question

**Introduction**

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function and $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Define the sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq 0}$ by $x_0=a$ and for $n\geq 0, x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$.

Assume now that the function $f(x)$ has the following property: There is a constant $L\in(0,1)$ such that for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ that following holds: $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq L|x-y|$.

**Already Shown / Proven**
$$|x_{k+1}-x_k|\leq L^k|x_1-x_0|$$
For all $n>m\geq 0$ the following holds: 
$$|x_n-x_m|\leq\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}L^k|x_1-x_0|$$

**Assignment**

Show that the sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is convergent.

**How far I am**

I've split up the right hand side of the inequality. And I see that i have to show that $|x_n-x_m|$ is a Cauchy sequence.

$$|x_n-x_m|\leq\sum_{k=m}^{n-1} L^{k}|x_1-x_0|=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}L^{k}|x_1-x_0|-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}L^{k}|x_1-x_0|=c \left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}L^{k}-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}L^{k}\right).$$

I've called $|x_1-x_0|=c$ because it's a constant. I also know that the 2 sums will end up as $\frac{1}{1-L}-\frac{1}{1-L}=0$ since they're geometric series. So the right hand side goes to 0 for n and m taken large enough.

I just don't see how i can formalize the proof. I don't have a clue how i can write down (in the form of a mathematically correct proof) that:

$\forall \epsilon >0$ there exists a natural number $N$, such that $m,n\geq N$ implies $|s_n-s_m|<\epsilon.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: We use your notation. Let $m\le n$. We have 
$$0\le |x_n-x_m|\le cL^m\sum_{0}^\infty L^{k}.\tag{1}$$ 
The series $\sum_1^\infty L^k$ converges, say to $d$. Then the left side of (1) is $\le cdL^m$.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. The only thing that's unclear to me is where the $L^m$ comes from in the right hand side of the inequality. Other than that, everything is clear :).

Comment: By what you wrote at the very beginning of the argument, we have $|x_n-x_m|\le c\sum_m^{n-1} L^k$. This is $\le c\sum_m^\infty L^k$. Take out the common factor $L^m$. We get $cL^m \sum_0^\infty L^j$.